# Python Os function called from Tkinter does not work when converted to .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Need your help lads and lasses!

I made a very simple hangman game with a GUI in Tkinter and created a button event that calls the following function to restart the game. This works fine as a Python script but does not work when converting script to .exe with Pyinstaller. ('Window" here is the root Tkinter window)

---

```
def restart_func():
    window.destroy()
    os.startfile("main.py")
    return
```

---

Any ideas why or alternative way of doing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: you would be better making it so that you could restart your game without destroying the window.......

Comment: i agree that the only reason a restart button would map to destroying your window then running your executable again is when you are just scratching that application off your to-do list and the next item in your to-do list is to delete that application.

Answer (score 1):

you should recreate your `window` and initialize it the same way you originially did.

```py
def restart_func():
    global window
    window.destroy()
    window = tk.Tk()
    run_gui_initialization_function()
```

this is usually why some applications prefer OOP instead of functional programming, as there is usually no global state in OOP programming, while for functional programming, your `run_gui_initialization_function` should reinitialize all of your global state variables again.

an alternative way people do this is as follows

```py
def main():
    # do main app here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this way you just need to run `main()` again after deleting your `window` if you ever need to restart your app.

**Edit:** okay, here's an easier to implement but too messy way to do this, you can start a detached version of your application from your executable ... but this is the wrong way to restart an application, and it might fail in some cases.

```py
from subprocess import Popen
import sys
def restart_func():
    window.destroy()
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        Popen(sys.executable,start_new_session=True)  # if running as executable
    else:
        os.startfile("main.py")  # if running as python script
```

Comment: Thanks all. Let me play around with this a bit and see what works best.